# Unique constraint based upon Grandparents in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table structure:

```
Grandparent - GrandParentId (PK)
Parent - ParentId (PK), GrandParentId (FK)
Child - ChildId (PK), ChildTypeId (FK), ParentId (FK)
```

I want a unique constraint saying that two children cannot have the same `ChildTypeId` if they have a common `GrandParentId`. Is this possible with SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with a UNIQUE constraint, but you can do it with a CHECK constraint that calls a UDF.

Write a UDF that takes a ChildId and queries a JOIN of Child and Parent to see if there is another child with the same GrandParentID and ChildTypeId.   If there is, return true/false.

Then in the CHECK constraint, call that function, passing the ChildId, and check if the result of the function is true/false.

You can also do it with a TRIGGER, but I prefer constraints.

Answer (score 2):

to speed up others stumbling upon this post, here is an SQL example of what Tab Alleman is suggesting:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Func_CousinsWithSameChildTypeId
(
    @childId uniqueidentifier,
    @parentId uniqueidentifier,
    @childTypeId uniqueidentifier
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @ResultVar bit

    SET @ResultVar = CASE 
        --assuming nullable - remove as necessary
        WHEN @parentId IS NOT NULL AND @childTypeId IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.Parents AS pAll
                INNER JOIN dbo.Children AS c ON c.ParentId = pAll.Id
            WHERE pAll.GrandParentId IN 
                (SELECT p1.GrandparentId
                 FROM dbo.Parents AS p1
                 WHERE p1.Id = @ParentId)
            AND c.Id <> @childId AND c.childTypeId = @childTypeId
        )
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @ResultVar

END
GO
```

then add the check constraint with something like

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Children] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CheckCousinsChildTypeId] CHECK  (([dbo].[Func_CousinsWithSameChildTypeId]([Id],[ParentId],[ChildTypeId])=(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Children] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CheckCousinsChildTypeId]
GO
```